# Pre phone interview follow up

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I live in Canada and applied for a job in a different city within the same province. Recruiter responded for an initial phone interview and we supposed to make an appointment. I replied to him with my availability (pretty flexible). And the recruiter didn't respond me back. I'm not sure how I can send a nice reminder or follow up email. Also I'm concerned if he noticed my location and changed his mind. I want to mention explicitly that I want to relocate.

I'll thank for any comment or help.

Bruce

Comment: Why don't you call the recruiter and ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ask, it's in the recruiter's best interest to get you a job (that's how they make their money) so if anything you're doing them a favour by making sure you land something via their referral.

A simple email like this would do:

> Hi [name], just wondered if we were scheduling a phone interview soon? [I'm flexible on the time of the call]/[Available between (time - time) on (date - date)]. My phone number is ...

Recruiters will typically have several candidates they're talking to (for several jobs) and some things slip through the cracks.

Best of luck on your job hunt!

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'll try and post here an update if I get any response

Comment: No worries, I had the same thoughts when hunting a while ago and it really isn't a problem!

Comment: Hi Jay, as promised. Worked well. I have passed 2 small none technical interviews and there is another technical interview coming